# using hbs engin and res.render shows page inside page

Tags: node.js, express, express-handlebars

so I have this login page which ask users for 2 inputs, when user enter wrong values, it suppose to show error message (line of text), instead it showed the whole page inside the current page, and the message is shown in this page.
[image]

here is my hbs code:

```html
<form  action="/loginadmin" method="POST">
        <div class="login100-form validate-form p-l-55 p-r-55 p-t-178" >
     <span class="login100-form-title">
      LogIn تسجيل الدخول
     </span>

     <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-16" data-validate="Please enter username">
      <input type="text" name="Mobilenumber" id="Mobilenumber" placeholder="Mobile Number رقم الجوال">
      <span class="focus-input100"></span>
     </div>

     <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Please enter password">
      <input  type="password" name="pass" id="pass" placeholder="Password الرقم السري">
      <span class="focus-input100"></span>
     </div>
</br>
     <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
      <button type="submit">
      Login دخول
      </button>
     </div>
             <p>{{ErrorMessage}}</p> <!-- this supposed to show error message -->
```

and here is the index.js part:

```js
//to access the page:
router.get('/Loginpage', function(req, res, next){
  res.render('/loginpage/index', {ErrorMessage: ''});

});

//form submission:
router.post('/loginadmin', function(req, res, next) {
  //take from input:

var mobileValue = req.body.Mobilenumber;
var passwordValue = req.body.pass;
console.log(mobileValue);
console.log(passwordValue);
// database connection to mongo .. removed for simplicity
  collection.find({mobile: mobileValue}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    if(!docs.length ){
      console.log('mobile is not registered');
      res.render("loginpage/index", {ErrorMessage: 'mobile is not registered'});//this part is causing the trouble I don't know why
    }else{
    //somethingelse//}
});
```

thanks,

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared your client-side JS code.

Comment: there is no JS in client side, its a .hbs file with html on it and {{ErrorMessage}} suppose to show the result once the form is submitted